# center a website in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I am trying to make a `websites in flex`. I am facing the problem that my website page is not centered. I Have searched `google` but haven't succeeded yet.

I am trying to center `<s:Application>` on my web browsers instead of starting from left hand
How can i do that?

Comment: Try by using width="100%" height="100%" for your <s:Application>. it will cover full page.

Comment: i dont want to cover full page ....

Comment: also, i have already tried this. I need to center everything not that it is on one side

Comment: ARe you trying to center your Flex content inside of your Flex application?  Or are you trying to center a SWF inside of a web page?  You may consider re-writing your question to make your purpose more clear.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com trying to center swf in web browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding: -

1) you are trying to embed swf in to HTML, if you want your swf to be at the center of HTML you have to embed swf in to one container on HTML side. Place your container position at center by providing x, y, height and width to it.

If you are using HTML you can do in this below way: -
Where as width="400" height="300" as your Flex Application swf width and height or keep swf width="100%" height="100%" 
You can replace AreaChart.swf with your swf name.

I think this can solve your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Tittle Here</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            html, body { height: 100%; margin:0; padding:0; text-align: center; }
            div#centered { border:0; height: 50%; width: 50%; position: absolute; left: 25%; top: 25%; color: black; }
        </style>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.registerObject("myId", "8.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="centered">    
            <object id="myId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="400" height="300">
            <param name="movie" value="AreaChart.swf" />
            <param name="scaleMode" value="showAll" />
            <param name-"quality" value="best" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="AreaChart.swf" width="400" height="300">
                <!--<![endif]-->
                <div id="altContent">
                    <h1>You need to upgrade your Flash player.</h1>
                    <p>
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

else

2) If you are trying to center your Flex content inside of your Flex application than you have to create one container and inside that you have to port your all logic including visual component etc.

Ex: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:local="*"
               width="800" height="600" >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;

            private function creationComp():void
            {
                mainContainer.x = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.width/2 - mainContainer.width/2;
                mainContainer.y = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.height/2 - mainContainer.height/2;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <local:MainContainer id="mainContainer" width="50%" height="50%" creationComplete="creationComp()"/>

</s:Application>
```

Where as MainContainer.mxml will contain for all visual component/elements.

This may help you.

There might be better solution to this.

Comment: I want to do the first thing you have listed. Can you please elaborate it a bit.