# Flex SWFObject Embed

Tags: apache-flex, swfobject

I am using the swfobject.js script file to embed an SWF dynamically to my aspx page.

From this [site](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation), I followed the code and shows up as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>SWFObject dynamic embed - step 3</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "100%", "95%", "9.0.0");
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myContent">
      <p>Alternative content</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I browse the page in IE, the whole flash swf is displayed, while on Chrome, it only displays partially (seems like the height of 95% is not being used).

I viewed the source from both IE and Chrome implementation and they are exactly the same. Any advise?

Comment: Besides the source, also pay attention to `CSS` styles.

Comment: can you test by adding height as 100% to your html and body as below:                       <style type="text/css"> 
  html, body  { height:100%; }</style>

Comment: Check below link this may help you: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225340/center-a-website-in-flex/11226482#comment14752208_11226482